# How to include a Custom list in one Sharepoint site in to another as a web part?

Tags: sharepoint

I have two share point web sites. One is a child web site of the other.  For example if my first site is myweb1, other one is myweb1/myweb2.

I have a custom list created in myweb1. I want to include that as a web part in number of web pages in both myweb1 and myweb1/myweb2 sites.

Including the web part in the same site which contains the custom list is not a problem. But how do I include it in the other site. The web part does not show up in the list.

I dont want to copy the content of custom list. I want pages in both sites that have included this list as a web part to be updated whenever the list content is changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Content Query Web Part](http://blogs.msdn.com/ecm/archive/2006/10/25/configuring-and-customizing-the-content-query-web-part.aspx) is your friend. You can use Content Query WebPart to achieve what you want, drop it to all the pages you want and Point it to the List that is present in the Root Site.